# Keep getting duplicate results in my report

Tags: sql, duplicates, repeat

```
I have this Query, I need it to pull a report of the registrants, but the report i get keeps duplicating the registrants on the result. 

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM registrants WHERE (paid='Y' AND course_id = '$course_info[0]' AND course_date = '$course_info[1]')

Can anyone tell me what is doing that?
```

Here is the rest of the code!!!
We want to get the results of the registrants that have paid. But when you generate the report it gives us the same; lets say 8 registrants once, then two times, then three and so on and so on until it shows each registrant at least 8 times

```
$course_report = $_POST['course_report'];

$course_info = explode('~',$course_report);
$course_info[0]; // course_id
$course_info[1]; // course_date

$select = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM registrants WHERE (paid='Y' AND course_id = '$course_info[0]' AND course_date = '$course_info[1]')";  

$result = mysql_query($select);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$course = $row['course'];
$coursedate = $row['course_date'];

$export = mysql_query($select);
$fields = mysql_num_fields($export); 
// Get header
for ($i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++) {
    $header .= mysql_field_name($export, $i) . "\t";
} 

// Get rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($export)) {
    $line = '';
    foreach($row as $value) {                                            
        if ((!isset($value)) OR ($value == "")) {
            $value = "\t";
        } else {
            $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim($line)."\n";
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected the table to see if the records are unique? Or do you know there are duplicates, and you want to make sure that the records returned are distinct based on `paid`, `course_id`, and `course_date`? By using `*`, you are basing the distinction on *every column in the row*, not just the three you have in your constraint.

Comment: What we want is to get the results from registrants that have paid the course fee. Here is the rest of the code maybe you can see something in it that is making the result duplicate the result when it gets exported to Excel. Sorry for the multiple comments but the code was too long to fit in one.

Comment: $course_report = $_POST['course_report'];
$course_info = explode('~',$course_report);
$course_info[0]; // course_id
$course_info[1]; // course_date
$select = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM registrants WHERE (paid='Y' AND course_id = '$course_info[0]' AND course_date = '$course_info[1]')";     
$result = mysql_query($select);

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$course = $row['course'];
$coursedate = $row['course_date'];    
$export = mysql_query($select);
$fields = mysql_num_fields($export); 

for ($i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++) {
    $header .= mysql_field_name($export, $i) . "\t";
}

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_row($export)) {
    $line = '';
    foreach($row as $value) {                                            
        if ((!isset($value)) OR ($value == "")) {
            $value = "\t";
        } else {
            $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim($line)."\n";
}

Comment: Please post your code in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: I will sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

You're selecting all columns from the table even though you're only filtering on three. Chances are that one of your columns has different data for each registrant. What do you want to be distinct? If you just want those three columns, then `SELECT DISTINCT PAID, COURSE_ID, COURSE_DATE` instead of all columns.

Comment: I hope that with the code above it better explains what we are trying to do, or where the mistake is in it!

Comment: The problem is still that you're selecting *. You need to select only those columns you need for you report. I would suggest running your select and reviewing the duplicates. A cursory look should reveal which column is different between the 'duplicate' records - probably a datetime field or something - and restrict your select only to the columns you need for the report such as registrant's name, course, etc.

Comment: Looks like the WHILE loops were nested in together. So the got separated and that fixed the issue of the data being generated multiple time. Now the only issue is that the header keeps repeating over and over on the report. Here is the code just for the header. // Get header
for ($i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++) {
    $header .= mysql_field_name($export, $i) . "\t";
}

Comment: I would be great to have someone tell me what is generating the header multiple times.